# Bleak - Python Bluetooth library: RuntimeError asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, python-asyncio, spyder

I'm trying to use *Bleak* , a Python library for Bluetooth devices management. Starting from an [example](https://pypi.org/project/bleak/#description) of use to find active Bluetooth devices

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

async def main():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(d)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I get a

```
File "C:\Users\ \Desktop\Python_BLE.py", line 25, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())

File "C:\Users\ \Miniconda3\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 34, in run
    "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

I'm running it on *Spyder 5.2.2* with *Python 3.7.10*.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: `File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Python_BLE.py", line 25, in <module>` Unless I'm sorely mistaken, there aren't 25 lines of code in your example.

Comment: Line 25 corresponds to _asyncio.run(main())_ as stated in the code. Missing lines are comments auto-generated by the editor.